# NavigationDrawer (Hamburger menu) Icon Image on Android

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I was searching on @android:drawable to find the ***3 horizontal bar image*** and could not find it. Where can I get it without creating it myself?

An example of that image:

[image: 3 horizontal bar button from facebook]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can download the material design official icon set here:

https://www.google.com/design/icons/

And have more information about it in here:

https://www.google.com/design/spec/resources/sticker-sheets-icons.html#sticker-sheets-icons-product-icons

Comment: wow thats a really complete catalog! Thanks very much! Will have it in mind for other icons :D

Comment: It really is! The material design guide is very useful for standard things like this. Hope I'd been useful too! :)

Answer (score 0):

Could this be it? https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/blob/master/navigation/drawable-xxhdpi/ic_menu_white_24dp.png

All the images you need are available in the material design repo:

https://github.com/google/material-design-icons